# toggleInlineStyle() is there a list or typing for the available inline styles?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am working on an editor using DraftJS, I've managed a few basic buttons using `toggleInlineStyle()` but I cannot seem to find in either the docs or in the typings for the available inline styles. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[native style](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/010fce785948edaf92bd9e81e8777784c1421545/src/model/immutable/SampleDraftInlineStyle.js) or [custom style](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-inline-styles#mapping-a-style-string-to-css) will be mapped to css.